# Laravel storage directory permission

Tags: php, html, laravel, ftp

I've deployed my laravel application via FTP and I get a 500 Internal Server Error and I think it is because of permission. The index page works, but when I click on some link or button which links to some other page, I get the 500 error.

I'm a real php and laravel noob and I need an explanation how I give storage permission like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/file-permissions-for-laravel-5-and-others#)

How do I cd into an online directory and execute these lines?

Comment: you need to give permission to Bootstrap also

Comment: But how do I do that?

Comment: what online control panel or ftp application are you using? e.g. directadmin/filezilla

Comment: I am using filezilla

Comment: rightclick the storage folder, at the bottom should be `file permissions`, set that to the desired permission level (e.g. `777` or `755`) and be sure to check the recursive subdirectory checkmark

Comment: okay I just did 755 on the whole project. still internal server error...

Comment: do you have the ability to turn on php errors? that would provide more insight as to what is going wrong.